# How do you execute server side code on doubleclick in a telerik radgrid?

Tags: telerik, postback, radgrid

How do you execute server side code on doubleclick in a telerik radgrid? I have a radbutton on my radgrid that executes server side code and I want doubleclick on a row to execute the same code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RowDblClick(sender, eventArgs) {
        // do post back? find button and call the click function?
    }
</script>

<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">
    <ClientSettings>
        <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" />
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top">
        <CommandItemTemplate>
            <telerik:RadButton ID="EditRadButton" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
        </CommandItemTemplate>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the grid, and then get the button that is its child, then invoke the click

```
function RowDblClick(sender, eventArgs) {
    var grid = $get('<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>');
    var button = $telerik.findControl(grid, "EditRadButton");
    button.click();
}
```

Comment: the reference to the grid is the first argument the event handler receives, so you don't need the $find(), just use the sender variable for the grid.